# Trying to understand synchronized methods

Tags: java, multithreading

For the code below, the expected output is:

```
Waiting for b to complete...
Total is: 4950
```

How come it can't print the `Total is..` ***first*** then `Waiting for b..` ***after***? I'd think `b.start()` could be executed **first** in some cases, then it holds onto `ThreadB`'s lock with `synchronized(this)` in `ThreadB.run()` thus blocking main from entering in `synchronized(b)`.

Is anything wrong with what I just stated?

```
public class ThreadA {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadB b = new ThreadB();
        b.start();

        synchronized(b) {
            try{
                System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
                b.wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Total is: " + b.total);
        }
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int total;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            for(int i=0; i<100 ; i++) {
                total += i;
            }
            notify();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you expect the outputs to be executed in a different order? They are always on the same thread. It won't matter if b's run method is executed before a is entering the synchronized block or not.

Comment: *Don’t* synchronize on a `Thread` instance. The documentation of the `Thread` class will tell you why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two output statements will **always** have the same order, because they are executed on one thread. Waiting for another thread to finish between them will not change their execution order.

If you put the "Total is ..." output to the end of b's `run()` then there might be a chance for seeing indeterministic orders of the outputs.

**EDIT - Please also note @Holger 's comment to this answer:**

> [...] in the unlikely, but still possible case that ThreadB’s synchronized block is executed first, its notify() call will have no effect as no-one is waiting yet and then, ThreadA’s wait() call may hang forever as there will be no subsequent notification.

Comment: Doh! I read the code wrong - thought it was how you described where printing of the Total is inside b's `run()`. Other than that, my description of how the threads obtain locks are correct, right?

Comment: I suspect that even if printing the total were inside the `run` method of `b`, you'd get exactly the same behaviour.  @Seelenvirtuose had a brilliant answer explaining why, but he's deleted it now.

Comment: @DavidWallace I agree. I think he deleted it, when he saw that the actual problem was the placement of the output statement.

Comment: @DavidWallace Could you guys paraphrase/explain Seelenvirtuose's answer as to why even if printing the total were inside the run method of b, you'd get exactly the same behaviour?

Comment: @Glide Basically it is so much more probable that the main thread will be allowed to continue execution up the `b.wait()` that it most probably will always be in the same order. That is because the main thread is already running and the new "b" Thread has to undergo the whole process of being scheduled etc ...

Comment: Yeah, I can copy-paste the relevant portion.  @Seelenvirtuose wrote: "The main thread is already running. Starting the new thread does not immediately start running it. It only asks the JVM to let this thread run sometime in the future. Usually, the JVM will not decide to directly suspend the main thread because switching threads is a costly operation."

Comment: Well, in the unlikely, but still possible case that `ThreadB`’s `synchronized` block is executed first, its `notify()` call will have no effect as no-one is waiting yet and then, `ThreadA`’s `wait()` call may hang forever as there will be no subsequent notification.

Answer (score -4):

Actual problem over here is you have only one thread "b" over here and you are calling wait() on b which is taking b thread to WAIT state and there is no other thread which can notify this thread and bring b back to runnign state.